# how do i save passwords when i need them later in plain tex (php)

Tags: php, database, email, encryption, passwords

I'm making a mail client in php. My problem is that I need to save the passwords in a database and later retrieve them in plain text when I'm sending mail (I need them for user authentication).

Is there a safe way to do that?

Comment: If mail only gets sent after user action, the user could enter the password (or some password that serves as the encryption key to the stored mail server password). However, I assume this is not the case, thus the need to store the password for later use. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct, i need the password as a paramenter when im sending and retriving a mail. Etc when the user is pressing inbox button the password is needed to fetch mail.

Comment: If the password is only needed when the user is active, could you just keep it in the session and not permanently store it? That's assuming the user would enter the password to first log in.

Comment: I don't know why i didn't thought of that earlier. Thanks!
(but is it safe?)

Comment: It would be more safe in the sense that it isn't permanently there, but by default session is stored in plaintext in temp files. You could define a custom way to store sessions using [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler), which would allow you to encrypt session data before storing it.

Comment: Thanks, im using session_set_save_handler() now and its working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Its best not to store passwords as plain text.

For authentication, generate a hash i.e MD5 of the password, then compare the hash stored in the database. If the hashes match then the user is authenticated.

If the user forgets their password, the password should be reset.

Comment: It sounds like the asker needs to send the password to a mail server. If this were just for a login system, then your advice is correct, but I don't think it's applicable to this scenario.

Comment: MD5 shouldn't be used for passwords, ever. Passwords should be hashed with a combination of hashing algorithms using a salt.

Answer (score 2):

If you however do need to store the secrets for later purposes (not for authentication as mentioned before), you can use some kind of encryption like PHP's

- mcrypt_encrypt http://php.net/mcrypt_encrypt
- mcrypt_decrypt http://php.net/mcrypt_decrypt

Pick a key per password and store that key somewhere else then your secrets. Probably the best option would be to extract a key based on some static parameters of the account that owns the password.

This application logic will also be needed for decrypting the password. So it would be nice if  the de/en-cryption logic runs somewhere isolated from your database storing the encrypted values.

Answer (score 0):

Craig is correct. However, I suspect your real question is "How can I save data for later use?"

In this case, you have a couple options:

- You can use a database such as MySQL, MSSQL, SQLite, or Oracle.
- You can write to a file on the server's hard disk

Answer (score 0):

You could query the password from the database.

Then after getting it, you can use the

```
fwrite(), fopen()
```

to open and write on your plaintext, google it, their are plenty of examples. but i agree with @craig1231, its not wise and safe to put vital inforamtions in plaintext and not hashing it.